# How to use Postman's Predefined Variables when importing Postman Collections into IntelliJ IDEA for using them with IntelliJ's HTTP Client Plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-http-client

Jet Brains has announced, that since the September, 2023, we can now [import collections from Postman](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/22438-import-from-postman-collections) and use them with [HTTP Client plugin](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html).

Migration from the Postman to IntelliJ sounds nice, as it enables one-place-for-everything approach and we can test web endpoints that we tested before with Postman, right from the IntelliJ IDEA, with its HTTP Client plugin.

But, how about [predefined variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/script-references/variables-list/)?

In many cases, people use Postman's predefined variables for different purposes, when they compose HTTP request. When Postman's collections containing predefined variables are now imported into IntelliJ IDEA', as `.http` files, these predefined variables are no longer interpolated/resolved anyhow, because that was specific feature of Postman.

For example, in Postman, we have a `${{guid}}` predefined variable and Postman generates random value per each HTTP request.

IntelliJ IDEA's HTTP Plugin, however, has no clue what it is, when having:

```
# @name My HTTP Request
POST {{someEndpointHere}}
Authorization: Basic someTextHere
someKey: {{$guid}}
```

I think this is pretty important stuff and it should have been considered by the plugins' authors.

Any ideas? any workarounds?

Comment: There is a related feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257966/HTTP-Client-should-provide-more-dynamic-variables.

Comment: @CrazyCoder thanks, but this thread was created 3 years ago. Do you know, whether there's any tangible update or a plan regarding this feature? We're just about to decide whether we'd migrate to IDEA's HTTP Client or not.

Comment: It's a planned feature, but with no ETA.

Answer (score 0):

Hi well I just had the same issue before me:

1. good news you can absolutely use preDef Variables in Intellij http client and they were introduced some time ago
   -> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/exploring-http-syntax.html#dynamic-variables

So in your your case it is just `{{$uuid}}` instead of $guid